# Elements resize as per screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to have a responsive page here. Its working fine for the background image, but I have no idea how to do it for the other div elements. I'm actually a beginner at this. So please explain to me how i should structure my elements. Thank you so much.

here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<title>PAGE</title>
</head>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="content">
CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. 
CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. 
CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. 
CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. 
CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. CONTENT. 
</div>

<div id="push">
</div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
&#169; Copyright 20XX
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```css
html
{
background-image: url(wildbull-crop.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-color:rgb(194,190,189);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

body
{
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#content
{
width:33%;
border:solid thin black;
background-color:white;
opacity:0.7;
}

#footer
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:orange;
}

#wrapper
{
min-height:100%;
width:100%;
border:solid thin white;
height:100%;
margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Research CSS3 media queries by screen size. Here is a good example to get you started:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries